# Наложение текста поверх другого текста

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

При наведении мыши на блок меню "УМОВИ", появляется выпадающий список, и этот список почему-то является менее приоритетным, чем остальные элементы на странице, которые находятся ниже, и получается так, что эти элементы налаживаются поверх этого списка.

Как сделать так, чтобы выпадающий список налаживался поверх элементов?

```js
var page_name = "home";

function in_array(needle, array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == needle)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}

function setActiveMenuItem() {
  var
    menu_items = document.getElementsByClassName("menu_item");

  for (var i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
    var
      menu_item = menu_items[i];

    if (menu_item.getAttribute("data-menu") == page_name) {
      menu_item.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  switch (page_name) {
    case "home":
      var
        menu_items = document.getElementsByClassName("menu_item");

      for (var i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
        var
          menu_item = menu_items[i],
          menu_dropdown = menu_item.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_menu");

        if (menu_dropdown.length) {
          menu_item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            this.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_menu")[0].classList.remove("hidden");
          }, false);
          menu_item.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            this.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_menu")[0].classList.add("hidden");
          }, false);
        }
      }

      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  setActiveMenuItem();
}, false);
```

```css
  @font-face {
  font-family: "Gothic";
  src: url("../fonts/Gothic.ttf");
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #edeef0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Gothic", sans-serif;
}

.clearfix {
  display: block;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: '';
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.trns150ms {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

#body {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#body .header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 235px;
  background-image: url("../images/header.png");
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#body .content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #b8b9ba;
}

#body .content #menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #878a8c;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 148px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  line-height: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item.active,
#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #d8d7dc;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .line {
  float: left;
  width: 3px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item .dropdown_menu {
  width: 105%;
  margin-left: -2.5%;
  background-color: #878a8c;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item .dropdown_menu .dropdown_menu_item {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item .dropdown_menu .dropdown_menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #d8d7dc;
}

#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item .dropdown_menu .dropdown_line {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0px 27.5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#body .content .page {
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

#body .content .page .symbolics {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#body .content .page .symbolics .symbolics_title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

#body .content .page .symbolics .symbolics_block {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #878a8c;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#body .content .page .symbolics .symbolics_block.finl {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#body .content .page .symbolics .symbolics_block .symbolics_block_title {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#body .content .page .symbolics .symbolics_block .symbolics_block_title,
#body .content .page .symbolics .symbolics_block .symbolics_block_text {
  text-align: center;
  ;
```

```html
<body class="noselect">
  <div id="body">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu_body">
          <div class="menu_item trns150ms" data-menu="home">ГОЛОВНА</div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="menu_item trns150ms" data-menu="about">ПРО НАС</div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="menu_item trns150ms" data-menu="terms">
            УМОВИ ↓
            <div class="dropdown_menu hidden">
              <div class="dropdown_menu_item trns150ms">РЕЖИМ <br />ДНЯ</div>
              <div class="dropdown_line"></div>
              <div class="dropdown_menu_item trns150ms">РОЗКЛАД <br />ЗАНЯТЬ</div>
              <div class="dropdown_line"></div>
              <div class="dropdown_menu_item trns150ms">ХАРЧУВАННЯ</div>
              <div class="dropdown_line"></div>
              <div class="dropdown_menu_item trns150ms">ОХОРОНА <br />ЗДОРОВ'Я</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="menu_item trns150ms" data-menu="photos">
            ФОТО ↓
            <div class="dropdown_menu hidden">
              <div class="dropdown_menu_item trns150ms">АТМОСФЕРА</div>
              <div class="dropdown_line"></div>
              <div class="dropdown_menu_item trns150ms">СВЯТА</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="menu_item trns150ms" data-menu="contacts">КОНТАКТИ</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page clearfix">
        <div class="symbolics">
          <div class="symbolics_title">СИМВОЛIКА НАШОГО САДОЧКА</div>

          <br /> <br />

          <div class="symbolics_hymn symbolics_block finl">
            <div class="symbolics_block_title">ГIМН</div>
            <br />
            <div class="symbolics_block_text">
              І<br /> Наш дитячий садочок чудовий, <br /> Дуже сонячний, теплий, як дім, <br /> Відкриває нам світ кольоровий.<br /> Тож мерщій у «Веселку» ходім! <br /> Приспів:
              <br /> «Веселка», «Веселка» - це радість і сміх, <br /> Турбота й тепло огортають усіх. «Веселка»,<br /> «Веселка» - це другий наш дім, <br /> Бо затишно й весело дітям у нім.<br /> ІІ <br /> Враз зустрінуть малят добрі люди,<br /> Суто
              весь із жінок колектив.<br /> Веселково і гарно всім буде,<br /> Повно безліч казкових тут див.<br /> Приспів:
              <br /> «Веселка», «Веселка» - це радість і сміх,<br /> Турбота й тепло огортають усіх. <br /> «Веселка», «Веселка» - це другий наш дім,<br /> Бо затишно й весело дітям у нім.<br />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="symbolics_hymn symbolics_block">
            <div class="symbolics_block_title">ГIМН</div>
            <br />
            <div class="symbolics_block_text">
              І<br /> Наш дитячий садочок чудовий, <br /> Дуже сонячний, теплий, як дім, <br /> Відкриває нам світ кольоровий.<br /> Тож мерщій у «Веселку» ходім! <br /> Приспів:
              <br /> «Веселка», «Веселка» - це радість і сміх, <br /> Турбота й тепло огортають усіх. «Веселка»,<br /> «Веселка» - це другий наш дім, <br /> Бо затишно й весело дітям у нім.<br /> ІІ <br /> Враз зустрінуть малят добрі люди,<br /> Суто
              весь із жінок колектив.<br /> Веселково і гарно всім буде,<br /> Повно безліч казкових тут див.<br /> Приспів:
              <br /> «Веселка», «Веселка» - це радість і сміх,<br /> Турбота й тепло огортають усіх. <br /> «Веселка», «Веселка» - це другий наш дім,<br /> Бо затишно й весело дітям у нім.<br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIV с классом `.menu_body` имеет статичную высоту в 100 пикселей, в эту часть помещается только название меню, все остальное вылезает за пределы данного DIV'а, поэтому не странно, что у него такое поведение.

Добавьте `position: relative` к классу `#body .content #menu .menu_body .menu_item .dropdown_menu` и ваша проблема решится.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Через 3 минуты можно будет пометить ответ, как верный.